# SQL query - Impossible to repeat a sum on different lines

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, subquery, repeat

I'm new to SQL and I can't solve this problem :

I have 2 tables in input :
The table "ORDER" :

| Parcel_num | Order_num |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 2 |

The table "PARCEL" :

| Parcel_num | Weight |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1000 |
| B | 500 |
| C | 1500 |
| D | 1000 |

I have to display this tab in output :

| Parcel_num | Order_num | Weight/order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 3000 |
| B | 1 | 3000 |
| C | 1 | 3000 |
| D | 2 | 1000 |

I'm able to get the weight/order using this query :

```
> SELECT ORDER.Order_num, SUM(PARCEL.Weight) AS SUM_WEIGHT  FROM PARCEL
> INNER JOIN ORDER ON PARCEL.Parcel_num=ORDER.Order_num  GROUP BY
> ORDER.Order_num
```

But i'm not able to repeat this sum for each parcel.
I've tried using subqueries but I get errors anyway...

Comment: Simply, change the group by from ORDER.Order_num to ORDER.Parcel_num

Comment: You have that information already in the `PARCEL` table, so it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT PARCEL.Parcel_num, SUM(PARCEL.Weight) AS SUM_WEIGHT  
FROM PARCEL
GROUP BY PARCEL.Parcel_num
```